# SSO Saml Protocol Binding Without Signature

Tags: single-sign-on, saml, spring-saml

I just start work with SSO Saml and have some confuses that would like to clear.
- If I have to encode AuthnRequest with three mechanisms Deflate encode, Base64 encode, URL encodes. Do I have to use HTTP-Redirect to send message request?
- I refer to https://docs.oasis-open.org/security/saml/v2.0/saml-bindings-2.0-os.pdf page 16 for HTTP-Redirect Biding.
- If I using HTTP-Redirect Biding. Do I have to provide all 4 parameters SAMLRequest=value&RelayState=value&SigAlg=value&Signature=value or just two parameters SAMLRequest=value&RelayState=value I already have enough condition to send request to IdP.

Answer (score 0):

> If I have to encode AuthnRequest with three mechanisms Deflate encode,
>   Base64 encode, URL encodes. Do I have to use HTTP-Redirect to send
>   message request? - I refer to
>   https://docs.oasis-open.org/security/saml/v2.0/saml-bindings-2.0-os.pdf
>   page 16 for HTTP-Redirect Biding. - If I using HTTP-Redirect Biding.

Yes, thats the requirement because in HTTP-Redirect you send the request as URL parameter hence need to minimize it in length/size.

> Do I have to provide all 4 parameters
>   SAMLRequest=value&RelayState=value&SigAlg=value&Signature=value or
>   just two parameters SAMLRequest=value&RelayState=value I already have
>   enough condition to send request to IdP.

That depends on what is require by IDP but SAMLRequest is mandatory AFAIK.

Comment: [That depends on what is required by IDP but SAMLRequest is mandatory AFAIK.] If I send Request with 4 parameters SAMLRequest=value&RelayState=value&SigAlg=value&Signature=value then it returns with status Succes. But when I send Request with 2 parameters SAMLRequest=value&RelayState=value then it return status Responder. Is it mean that  IDP require must have 4 parameters? @WZee

Comment: That clearly means the issue it at IDP(Responder). There should be related error message. I'd suggest you to check it with IDP administrator.